# Time dependent conditions

Tags: php, time

I'm trying to display a message on my website that is dependent on time of day and day of the week, its further complicated by the need to display the name of the day 24h after 2pm on the current day.

So far i have this which is close but doesn't seem to be correct, plus it's horrendously ugly and unsimple.

Can somebody please point out why/where it's not functioning as intended?

```
<?php if (date("w") != 0 && date("w") != 6 && date("w") != 5):
    $future_date = strtotime('tomorrow 14:00 Europe/London');
    $remaining = $future_date-strtotime('now');
    $tomorrow = strtotime('today 14:00 +601 minutes');
    $c_time = mktime('H:i');
    $open = strtotime('yesterday 14:00');
    $close = strtotime('today 14:00'); ?>

<?php if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close): ?>
 <div class="margin-top-5">
 <p style="padding:10px 0; font-size: 12px;">Only <span class="timerHighlight">
  <?php echo date('H', $remaining);?> hours, <?php echo date('i', $remaining);?> minutes</span> left to get this product delivered on <span style="color:orange; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
    <?php echo date('l', $tomorrow);?></span> using <strong>'Next Working Day'!</strong></p>
    </div>
  <?php else: ?>
    <p><b>*Order before 2pm for next day delivery.</b></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please clearly explain _how_ it is not working. (As an unrelated side note, you made me look [this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) up…)

Comment: `strtotime('now')`? That is simply... hideous. that's what `time()` is for. And if you're requiring a specific  timezone, you should use that timezone EVERYWHERE. since it's only on your `future_date`, all the other strtotime calls will simply use the default system timezone.

Comment: @Marc B Its an example from the Doc on php.net ;-) I get crazy when i see more than one open/close tag in a script :)

Comment: To clarify the 'not working part', at the moment it simply returns the else statement of "*Order before 2pm for next day delivery." regardless of the time set.

Comment: Simplyfy tips: `date("w") != 0 && date("w") != 6 && date("w") != 5` can done like `!in_array(date("w"),array(0,6,5),true)`

Comment: `print mktime('H:i');` wont work `Warning: mktime() expects parameter 1 to be long`, check that first.

Comment: And yes its ugly as hell, i'm trying to get it working before making it simple and clean. I'm novice level so excuse the lack of basics!

Comment: Please use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: You could probably also take a nose at the `DateTime` object if you're aiming to make things look a bit nicer (and make date comparison less messy) : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Looks like it's working now, still ugly but working! mktime('H:i'); changed to mktime(); and timezone added to all strtotime(). I'll post up the working code . Thanks everyone for the help, steep learning curve but all good points made.

Answer (score 0):

I love the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes for this kind of thing.
I've taken a stab at what it looks like you're doing and so you should be able to work it out by using the following as a reference.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$orderWithin = null;
$deliveryDate = null;

switch ($now->format('w')) {

    // Order before 6pm Monday-Thursday and get it next day
    case 1: // Monday
    case 2: // Tuesday
    case 3: // Wednesday
    case 4: // Thursday
        $orderWithin = clone $now;
        $orderWithin->setTime(18, 00, 00);
        // Next day delivery
        $deliveryDate = clone $now;
        $deliveryDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        break;

    // Order before 6pm Friday and get it next working day (Monday)
    case 5: // Friday
        $orderWithin = clone $now;
        $orderWithin->setTime(18, 00, 00);
        // Next working day delivery
        $deliveryDate = clone $now;
        $deliveryDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        break;

    // Order on Sunday or Saturday then get it Tuesday
    case 0: // Sunday
        $orderWithin = clone $now;
        $orderWithin->setTime(23, 59, 59);
        // Tuesday delivery
        $deliveryDate = clone $now;
        $deliveryDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    case 6: // Saturday
        $orderWithin = clone $now;
        $orderWithin->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $orderWithin->setTime(23, 59, 59);
        // Tuesday delivery
        $deliveryDate = clone $now;
        $deliveryDate->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
        break;
}

$orderWithinInterval = $orderWithin->diff($now);

$orderWithinString = "{$orderWithinInterval->d} day(s), {$orderWithinInterval->h} hour(s), {$orderWithinInterval->i} minute(s)";

$deliveryDateString = "{$deliveryDate->format('D jS M')}";

?>

<p>Order within <?= $orderWithinString ?> to get your item delivered by <?= $deliveryDateString ?>.</p>
```

My output looked something like this:

> Order within 0 day(s), 2 hour(s), 29 minute(s) to get your item delivered by Fri 19th Aug.

Comment: If you use [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) you don't need to do any cloning

Comment: Thanks for the input Tom, that's really useful, i'll take a closer look.

Comment: No problem. If this solves you problem remember to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Revised version that now works as expected:

```
<?php if (!in_array(date("w"),array(0,6,5),true)):
                      $future_date = strtotime('tomorrow 14:00 Europe/London');
                      $remaining = $future_date-strtotime('now');
                      $tomorrow = strtotime('today 14:00 +601 minutes Europe/London');
                      $c_time = mktime();
                      $open = strtotime('yesterday 13:59 Europe/London');
                      $close = strtotime('today 13:59 Europe/London'); ?>

                      <?php if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close): ?>
                      <div class="margin-top-5">
                          <p style="padding:10px 0; font-size: 12px;">
                              Only <span class="timerHighlight">
                                                <?php echo date('H', $remaining);?> hours, <?php echo date('i', $remaining);?> minutes</span> left to get this product delivered on <span style="color:orange; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
                                                <?php echo date('l', $tomorrow);?></span> using <strong>'Next Working Day'!</strong></p>
                      </div>
                  <?php else: ?>

                      <p><b>*Order before 2pm for next day delivery.</b></p>
                  <?php endif; ?>


                      <br>
                  <?php endif; ?>
```

Problem areas seemed to be mktime('H:i'); and timezone on strtotime(). next step is to clean up and make it efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I've now taken it a bit further and made it work for 3 different scenarios, it's still bloated and ugly as hell, but as this is my first proper attempt at a making something for a real world situation i'm just happy it works!

Feel free to pick it to pieces and point out the best practice methods:

```
<!--Weekdays-->
              <?php if (date("w") == 1 || date("w") == 2  || date("w") == 3 || date("w") == 4):?>
                 <?php $future_date = strtotime('tomorrow 14:00 Europe/London');
                  $remaining = $future_date-strtotime('now');
                  $tomorrow = strtotime('today 14:00 +601 minutes Europe/London');
                  $c_time = mktime();
                  $open = strtotime('yesterday 13:59 Europe/London');
                  $close = strtotime('today 13:59 Europe/London'); ?>

                  <?php if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close): ?>
                      <div class="margin-top-5">
                          <p style="padding:10px 0; font-size: 12px;">
                              Only <span class="timerHighlight">
                            <?php echo date('H', $remaining);?> hour(s), <?php echo date('i', $remaining);?> minute(s)</span> left to get this product delivered on <span style="color:orange; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
                            <?php echo date('l', $tomorrow);?></span> using <strong>'Next Working Day'!</strong></p>
                      </div>
                  <?php else: ?>
                     <br>
                    <small>*Order before 2pm for next working day delivery.</small>
                  <?php endif; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>

<!--friday-->
              <?php if (date("w") == 5):?>
                  <?php
                    $future_date = strtotime('next tuesday 14:00 Europe/London');
                    $remaining = $future_date-strtotime('now Europe/London');
                    $tomorrow = strtotime('next tuesday Europe/London');
                    $c_time = mktime();
                    $open = strtotime('yesterday 13:59 Europe/London');
                    $close = strtotime('today 13:59 Europe/London');
                  ?>

                      <?php if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close): ?>
                      <div class="margin-top-5">
                          <p style="padding:10px 0; font-size: 12px;">
                              Only <span class="timerHighlight">
                            <?php echo date('H', $remaining);?> hour(s), <?php echo date('i', $remaining);?> minute(s)</span> left to get this product delivered on <span style="color:orange; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
                            <?php echo date('l', $tomorrow);?></span> using <strong>'Next Working Day'!</strong></p>
                      </div>
                      <?php else: ?>
                          <br>
                          <small>*Order before 2pm for next working day delivery.</small>
                      <?php endif; ?>

                  <?php endif; ?>

<!-- Weekend-->
              <?php if (date("w") == 0 || date("w") == 6):?>
                  <?php
                  $future_date = strtotime('next monday 14:00 Europe/London');
                  $remaining = $future_date-strtotime('now Europe/London');
                  $tomorrow = strtotime('next tuesday 14:00 +601 minutes Europe/London');
                  $number_days = (strtotime('next tuesday') - strtotime('now Europe/London'))  / (60 * 60 * 24);
                  ?>

                  <div class="margin-top-5">
                      <p style="padding:10px 0; font-size: 12px;">
                          Only <span class="timerHighlight">
                        <?php echo substr($number_days, 0, 1); ?> Day(s) <?php echo date('H', $remaining);?> hour(s) <?php echo date('i', $remaining);?> minute(s)</span> left to get this product delivered on <span style="color:orange; font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">
                        <?php echo date('l', $tomorrow);?></span> using <strong>'Next Working Day'!</strong></p>
                  </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
```